# Expected Value Word Problem

Tags: probability

I have another problem, that is so:

The probability that a roulette wheel stops on a red number is 18/37. For each bet on “red” you are returned twice your bet (including your bet) if the wheel stops on a red number, and lose your money if it does not.

If you bet $1 on each of the 10 consecutive plays, what is your expected winnings?

I started the question by declaring my random variables. I also know that each spin of the roulette wheel is independent of each other.

let X be the number of wins in the 10 consecutive plays

X ~ Binomial(10, 18/37), for any x such that $1 \leq x\leq 10$

By definition, my expected value function will look:
$E(x)=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{x=1}^{10} 3xf(x)$

What I am confused about is, how I determine my upper bound for my wins (how many wins can I get in 10 rolls), so that I can split my summation into two summations.

Since I do not know my probability distribution function, is my assumption that X follows a Binomial distribution correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct $($assuming you are talking about French Roulette, which has no $00)$ that $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(10,\frac{18}{37})$.

However, you've miscalculated. If you win, then you are given twice your bet *including* your bet, *not in addition to* your bet. That is, if you bet on red and win, then you only *double* your bet, not triple it. Your net gain for each win, then, is only a dollar, since you're betting a dollar each time.

You'd be better off starting by computing your expected number of wins, which is just $10\cdot\frac{18}{37}$. At that point, the answer will depend on what is meant by "expected winnings."

If it means "expected *net* gain," then note that you will gain a dollar for each win and lose a dollar for each loss, so since your expected losses are $10\cdot\frac{19}{37},$ then your expected net gain is $10\cdot\frac{18}{37}-10\cdot\frac{19}{37}=-\frac{10}{37}$ dollars.

If it means "expected gain," then the answer is simply $10\cdot\frac{18}{37}$ dollars.

If it means "expected total amount that you will be given by the croupier," then the answer will be $2\cdot10\cdot\frac{18}{37}$ dollars. (**Note**: If you simply subtract the $10$ dollars that you bet from this, then you will find the expected net gain in another way.)

---

**Addendum**: More generally, suppose that you play $n$ independent games with win probability $\theta.$ Let $X$ be the number of wins, so that $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(n,\theta).$ Then your expected number of wins is $$\Bbb E[X] = \sum_{x=0}^n\binom{n}{x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x},$$ but that's a bear to actually calculate. Instead, we will let $X_k$ be the number of wins on the $k$th trial for $1\le k\le n,$ so that $X\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}(\theta)$ for each $k,$ and $$X=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k.$$ Since expectation is linear over sums of random variables, then $$\Bbb E[X]=\Bbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n\Bbb E[X_k]=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{x=0}^1x\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}=\sum_{k=1}^n1\cdot\theta^1(1-\theta)^{1-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\theta=n\theta.$$

So, our expected number of wins is $n\theta,$ which in your particular example is $10\cdot\frac{18}{37}.$

Comment: I see. The question asks for the net gain. Intuitively it makes sense it multiply the # of plays * percentage. Just to clarify, since all the plays are independent of each other and not disjoint, why do we multiply 10*(18/37), we are adding 18/37 10 times, instead of (18/37)^10, we are multiplying (18/37) 10 times.

Comment: I have expanded my answer to explain that (and have added a note to the bit about the croupier).

Comment: I see, your little proof cleared it up for me. Essentially, E(X) = n * p, where p is the probability of a success.

Answer (score 0):

This is linear. The roulette is spun independently and one return is not dependent on another.

Your expected return for every game is 2*18/37.
Hence, for 10 games it is 10*2*180/37 = 360/37.

Remember that you are not winning, but rather losing, since you put in 10 and getting 9.73